# Linear regression: in practice, how likely is it for $A^\top A$ to be non-invertible and what fundamentally causes it?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, multiple-regression, predictive-models, linear

The linear regression problem involves solving,

$$\|Ax - b\|_2^2$$

where $A$ is the data matrix and $b$ is the target vector.

The solution to this problem is known to be,

$$x^\star = (A^\top A)^{-1} A^\top b$$

whenever $A^\top A$ is invertible or equivalently, positive definite.

I am curious as to,

1. in practice how likely is it for $A^\top A$ to be non-invertible.
2. This means some entries in $A^\top A$ is linearly dependent. What is the implication on the data matrix itself? (i.e., what property must $A$ satisfy for $A^\top A$ to be non-invertible)

Comment: Maybe this would answer you: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1840801/why-is-ata-invertible-if-a-has-independent-columns

Comment: (1) is unanswerable, because "practice" could mean anything.  You likely can answer (2) yourself by recalling the interpretation of matrices as linear transformations.